# Last Page that User Visited is Not Saving in "document.referrer"

Tags: javascript, redirect, event-handling, local-storage, browser-history

I am trying a user to redirect back to the blog he was reading after signup & tried multiple methods but user is getting redirected to either 2nd last blog or the same page (signup). Details below.

**LINK TO SITE I NEED HELP WITH**

- http://mintymind.flywheelsites.com/

**GOAL**

- A user reads 1 blog, clicks on 2nd blog & gets redirected to signup page.
- User gives his email & signs up.
- Signup page gets refreshed & shows back button (to go to last blog user was reading)

**WHATS HAPPENING**

- For some reason, the "Last blog" from where user gets redirected to is not getting stored in `javascript: history.go(-1)` or `window.history.back()`
- When I use `-1` in history functions mentioned above, it stays on the same sign page probably because it was refreshed but when I even user `-2` in those above history functions, it goes to "2nd last blog" user read.

**OTHER SOLUTION I TRIED**

```js
if (!sessionStorage.alreadyClicked) {
    var referrer = document.referrer;
    console.log(referrer);
      
      
    localStorage.setItem("protectedReferrer", referrer);
    var protectedReferrerForInsertion = localStorage.getItem("protectedReferrer");
      
    console.log("Saved Variable was" + protectedReferrerForInsertion);   
}

document.querySelector("#back-button-referrer a").setAttribute("href", protectedReferrerForInsertion);
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting URLs don't get added to history or the referrer.  You can't rely on those to record where to send somebody back to when that URL originally redirected.

They way to solve this issue is to use a URL parameter of the page to return to when redirecting to the signup page.  In other words: `/second-blog-article` should redirect to `/signup?back=/second-blog-article`.  That `back` parameter needs to be passed the entire way through the sign up process and then you redirect to it once sign up is complete.

Comment: Thankyou for quick reply Stephen. I can pass the URL param from `document.referrer` but it would get overwritten again when the page refreshes. Can you please tell me how can I stop that overwriting after reload behaviour?

Comment: That param shouldn't be the referrer.  It needs to be the page URL of the page that redirects when the redirect is created.  If you edit your question to show the code that redirects to the signup page I can help you modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey using session solved my problem. Here is the code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    if (top.location.pathname === '/signup/'){

        var sessionCheck = sessionStorage.getItem('visited');
        
        if(sessionCheck == null || 0 ){
            sessionStorage.setItem("visited", 0);
        }
    
        var visited = sessionStorage.getItem('visited');
        
          if (visited == 0) {
            var referrer = document.referrer;
        
            sessionStorage.setItem("localReferrer", referrer);
            sessionStorage.getItem('localReferrer');
    
            $("#back-button-referrer a").attr("href", sessionStorage.getItem('localReferrer'));
            sessionStorage.setItem("visited", 1);
        }
        else{
            $("#back-button-referrer a").attr("href", sessionStorage.getItem('localReferrer'));
        }
    }

});
```